# Get sum of the values in multiply lists generated by comprehension list in the loop

Tags: python, list, loops, sum, zip

I have a comprehension list inside a loop that will result in multiply lists, like below:

[1,3,5,7,9,12]
[7,9,0,4,12,3]
[9,4,8,3,1,6]
[21,11,12,32,2,12]

I don't need this lists themselves, but only the sum of same index values in this lists, like this:

[38,27,25,54,33]
(where, for example, 38 is first values in every list 1+7+9+21)

I have tried to do it with combination of list/map/sum/zip:

```
list(map(sum,zip([func(data,x) for x in list(range(num)])))
```

where **"list(range(num)"** is number of lists that need to be summed,
and **"func(data,x)"** is function that generates the lists itself

but its not workings, as zip(), only takes data like zip(a,b,c)

It looks simple, but i already spent two days trying to understand how to solve this case.

is there is any way i can get the sum of these lists?

Comment: is the `[46,27,26,54,33]` just a random example? that does not correspond with your list examples, `sum` of `[1,3,5,7,9,12]` is not 46

Comment: You want the sum of elements inside every list or the sum of l[0] for every list, then the sum of l[1] of every list etc?

Comment: Sorry for misleading description. I need a list with sum of the same index values from lists that was generated in loop (you can check my update in the question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your results list, and all sublists in said list are of the same length - put them all in a list together and simply-

```py
[sum(item[i] for item in results) for i in range(len(results[0]))]
```

Where `results` is your list of results.

Not entirely sure how you're generating these results but I'm assuming this is how you get said list of results-

```py
[func(data,x) for x in range(num)]
```

(please do not `list(range(num))`, `range` returns a generator that is efficient for list comprehension)

You simply have to do

```py
results = [func(data,x) for x in range(num)]
print([sum(item[i] for item in results) for i in range(len(results[0]))])
```

again, this is assuming `func(data, x)` returns a list (of constant length across this process)

### Input

```py
# assume results = [[1,3,5,7,9,12],[7,9,0,4,12,3],[9,4,8,3,1,6],[21,11,12,32,2,12]]
print([sum(item[i] for item in results) for i in range(len(results[0]))])
```

### Output

```py
[38, 27, 25, 46, 24, 33]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me make a simple conceptual program. See if it helps:

```
# Inputs
l1 = [3,4,5]
l2 = [6,7,8]

input_lists = []
input_lists.append(l1)
input_lists.append(l2)
print(input_lists)
# prints [[3,4,5], [6,7,8]]

#Output
print([sum(i) for i in input_lists])
```